# Python | Getting Filename of File Which is Using Specified Class

Tags: python, class

I wrote a class on a file called `a.py` and am running a program on `main.py` that uses the class from `a.py`. I'm trying to get the filename of the file that's running the class on `a.py` from `a.py` so that running the class from `a.py` returns `main.py` since that's the file that's using the class.

If this is confusing I can explain more.

```
class a:
  def __init__(self):
    print(filename of file thats using this class)
```

Comment: How should they communicate? With threads?

Comment: fixed it using `sys.argv[0]`

Comment: that's a good way too! You can post your solution (and in case sign as the correct one) so that it could be useful for other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using `sys.argv[0]` to find the running file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.where_am_i = None

# assume this is in a separate file
f = foo()
# get name of current file -- this is a Python feature
f.where_am_i = __file__
print(f.where_am_i)
```

Output:

```
<insert file where f was initialized here>
```

Comment: This only works if the user passes in the filename using `__file__` manually though, is there a way to retrieve it from the class file without having the user input it in?